# Setting background image in java

Tags: java, android, background

So basically, I have an xml, which i want to reuse. The content is somewhat the same, only the background is different and a few adjustment too.. How can I go about to do this.. I have tried `View.setBackGroundDrawable(R.drawable.sample);` but it does not work. My app crash. I've placed my image inside one of the drawable folder though.

Comment: What error messages you got from the crash?

Comment: Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation... .java:1053)

Comment: could you paste the stack trace from your logcat?

Comment: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygo ... .java:993) this look totally foreign..

Comment: @Sahara : what view is it? is it an image view, button etc?

Comment: @Sahara : is it a linear layout? If it is that then the code provided by omi0301 should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to assign an id for your layout on your xml so that on your java code, you can set a different layout for it.. Here is an example:

```
 //assuming your Layout is named linearlayout1:
 LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);
 ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sample);
```

You can also create if statements before setting your background like:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);
if( yourifstatement) {
ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sample);
}
```

If it is a RelativeLayout, then the same code applies, just change LinearLayout to RelativeLayout.

If this is not the problem, please post your LogCat.

Comment: Can you explain the LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1); why is it R.id.. instead of R.layout

Comment: Because you are naming your LinearLayout on your activity. Your not yet setting the content (which is used for xml. Linear Layout is just a part of an xml). You are setting the background of the layout on ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sample);

Comment: @Sahara - And also, your LinearLayout is only a part of the xml that you would like to re-use.

Comment: i dont get it.. why am i creating a new layout??when I already have an xml but my xml has no background image and i want to set the image in the java class.. so that I can reuse that same xml in my other java class by just using different background image but with same xml.

Comment: @Sahara - The answer above only shows how to set an image background for 1 xml that can be used on different activities. It is not to create a new layout.