# Android Studio: How to change the Background to jpg. images using OnclickListener

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

So far I know how to change the Background's color via html codes. Now I am Trying to change the background of the Layout of my main activity to different images using a button click. If possible using only one single button.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The following code is from this link [Setting background image in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390864/setting-background-image-in-java) from Omi0301.

```
//assuming your Layout is named linearlayout1:
 LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);
 ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sample);
```

All you do is create a layout variable and set its background resource with the image that you would like it to be.

Answer (score 1):

try to use "setImageResource" instead the "setBackgroundResourse"

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

main.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:text="changeColor" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button button;
LinearLayout mainLayout;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mainLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newImage);

    }
});
}
}
```

Comment: It is giving an  "cannot resolve symbol." error on the last line.