# How to set another image responsively on background [attached]..?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need to set an image inside the square box under the hanger, what is the best technique to set the new image over this background to exactly fit inside the box in case of small or large screen devices.
[image: Background on Relative or Linear layout]

Comment: Show us *what you tried so far*. So that we can get understand. Post some of your *xml* code from which this *layout* you made.

Comment: open the image to see the background

Comment: It is a layout? if yes put here the xml code.

Comment: it is a png image only

Comment: convert this image to 9.patch image, with the help of 9 patch image you can archive easily, without losing image quality of hanger image

Comment: not about the image quality atleast read the description

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390864/setting-background-image-in-java